# How to loop JSON data object array

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I have a an `Ajax` request which runs a functions following code:

```
$all_jobs = JobPost::select('id','job_title','job_category','application_deadline')
    ->where('application_deadline','>=',$today)
    ->where('job_published_status',0)
    ->where('job_posts.status','Active')
    ->orderBy('id','DESC')
    ->where('user_id',$request->id)
    ->paginate(20);
    return response()->json($all_jobs);
```

when logging the returned data I get the following structure:

`console.log(data)`

[image]

Now when I loop through the data using:

`$.each(data, function(index,company){
                console.log(company);
            });`

the `console.log(company);`  returns the following structure:

`0:{id: 12, job_title: "Job Title for 12", job_category: "engineer-architects", application_deadline: "2018-07-27 00:00:00"}
1:{id: 11, job_title: "Job Title for 11", job_category: "garments-textile", application_deadline: "2018-07-19 00:00:00"}
2:{id: 10, job_title: "Job Title for 10", job_category: "accounting-finance", application_deadline: "2018-07-19 00:00:00"}
3:{id: 2, job_title: "Game Developer", job_category: "bank-non-bank-fin-institution", application_deadline: "2018-07-19 00:00:00"}
4:{id: 1, job_title: "Game Developer", job_category: "accounting-finance", application_deadline: "2018-07-26 00:00:00"}
length:5`

But if I try to access using `console.log(company[0])` in the loop

I get the data like this :

`{id: 12, job_title: "Job Title for 12", job_category: "engineer-architects", application_deadline: "2018-07-27 00:00:00"}`

But I also get an error saying:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null`

Also when I try to access property in the loop like this:

`console.log(company[0].id)`

I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Now my question is how can I loop through the `data` and get all the values.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the index provided in your Each function like so:

```
$.each(data, function(index,company){
     console.log(data[index]); // here is the company object
     // or access the company directly
     console.log(company); // same here = company object
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this is paginated data. When I  use `get()` rather than `pagination()`  then I can access the data.

Answer (score 0):

into `company` object you get the current array's index, i.e. you must access the desired property without an index, i.e. `console.log(company.id)` within the `each` loop. if you want to access with an index, then you should use `data` object, i.e. `console.log(data[0])` or `console.log(data[0].id)` or `console.log(data[index])` within the loop.

Comment: I have tried this method. Can't access the data. I forgot to mention this is `paginated` data. When I don't use `pagination()` and instead of `pagination()` I use `get()` then I can access the data.